# Beamer presentation with Pandoc and Markdown - Persian characters don't show properly

Tags: markdown, pandoc, beamer

I have a simple markdown like this:

```
---
dir: rtl
title: "درس روش پژوهش و ارائه"
author: "امیر شبانی"
date: "یک‌شنبه - ۱ دی ۱۳۹۸"
---
```

I save it in a file named `Presentation.md` and compile using this command:

```
pandoc Presentation.md -t beamer -o Presentation.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="Sahel"
```

The command runs without any error, but the font is not showing properly:

[image]

If I change the font from `Sahel` to `BNazanin`, it works fine:

[image]

But I'm interested in `Sahel` font. Is there any way I can fix it?

I don't think the font is corrupt, because it's showing fine in other programs, such as

VSCode:

[image]

Telegram:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Comment: This is probably more of a LaTeX issue. Maybe the fine folks over at https://tex.stackexchange.com can help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by [@tarleb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434539/beamer-presentation-with-pandoc-and-markdown-persian-characters-dont-show-pro#comment105207666_59434539), I asked my question on [TeX.StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522248/134078) and got an answer. The person that answered the question doesn't have an Stack Overflow account, so I'm just gonna copy [their answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522290/134078) here, in case someone finds this question first.

All that was needed was to specify the `-V lang=ar` in the original command, so that `Pandoc` doesn't load the default English script of the font. The font is Persian, but apparently since Arabic and Persian have similar letters, setting the language to Arabic works. So I can achieve what I wanted in two ways:

**Specify the language in the command, when compiling:**

Using this command,

```
pandoc pres.md -t beamer -o pres.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="Sahel" -V lang=ar
```

we can see that it works:

[image]

**Specifying the language in the markdown file's metadata (Which I personally prefer)**

So my markdown file would look like this:

```
---
lang: ar
dir: rtl
title: "درس روش پژوهش و ارائه"
author: "امیر شبانی"
date: "یک‌شنبه - ۸ دی ۱۳۹۸"
---
```

And we can see that this method works as well:

[image]

Comment: What text editor did you choose to write down Persian markdown ?